# TypeORM: force eager mode on both sides of relation

Tags: node.js-typeorm

I am approaching TypeORM to find out whether it would be a nice choose for the game i'm developing.

This is the configuration of two related entities I have:

```ts
import Tile from "./Tile";

@Entity('player')
export default class Player {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id!: number

    @Column()
    name!: string

    @Column()
    x!: number
    @Column()
    y!: number
    @Column()
    z!: number

    @ManyToOne((type) => Tile, {eager: true})
    @JoinColumn([
        {name: 'x', referencedColumnName: 'x'},
        {name: 'y', referencedColumnName: 'y'},
        {name: 'z', referencedColumnName: 'z'},
    ])
    tile!: Tile
}
```

```ts
import Player from "./Player"
  
@Entity('tile')
export default class Tile {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id!: number

    @Column()
    type!: string

    @Column()
    x!: number
    @Column()
    y!: number
    @Column()
    z!: number

    @OneToMany(() => Player, player => player.tile)
    players!: Promise<Player[]>
}
```

With this configuration i can access player.tile and get the reference to the tile because it has an eager loading, but if i load a Player, i also compulsory (for other game purposes) need to be able to access to player.tile.players without waiting for a promise or it would turn my whole code into an awful async/await creature.

Is there any way I can forcefully load also the non-owning side of the relation with eager mode? Obviously I would carefully design what must be loaded immediately and what can be loaded with lazy mode.

Thank you for any help!